# Custom InfoWindow size/pointer position in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map application that can be seen here:

http://chrismcaleenan.com/map/?page_id=25

Each of the Malaysian states in the application will have an InfoWindow that displays additional information. You can see an example of this by mousing over 'Kedah' either in the main data table on the right or on the state itself in the map.

The problem, as you can see, is that the map pans in order to position the InfoWindow. Is there a way to fix the map position and set the InfoWindow size or position so that it is fully displayed without panning? In the Kedah example, one could have the InfoWindow positioned directly to the right and/or use a shorter tail.

One option would be to create a custom graphic for each state, but I'd rather avoid this as I will be running into the same issue with add'l data (e.g. click Kedah to zoom - will have InfoWindows on all data points on zoom).

If you're playing around double-clicking the water will zoom back out and reset map.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to pan map to inforwindow position?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and sometimes the pan pulls the mouse outside of the state, which causes the `InfoWindow` to disappear. I know that's not what you want. The Google Maps demo catalog includes a sample that I think will give you what you want for your map. It's named [SmartInfoWindow](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/smartinfowindow/smartinfowindow.html). Take a look, click on some of the markers, check out how the SmartInfoWindow behaves, and see if that might help you achieve what you want. It's not perfect, but it keeps the pan at the absolute minimum.